# PDF file not rendering the same after system reinstallation (MikTex, TeXMaker)

Tags: miktex, texmaker, rendering

I reinstalled system recently.

From my software archives, I can say that I was using Texmaker 5.0.4 with basic-miktex 2.9.6942 or 2.9.7342 (probably 2.9.7342), install last year.

After system reinstallation, I tried installing basic-miktex 21.6 and rendered document using it but document looked broken.
So I reinstalled Miktex 2.9.7342 and Texmaker 5.0.4 hoping that it would render the same as before, but resulting document had the same issue.

**Document issue description**
I use FancyHeader and whenever header is on 2 text lines, text body or images overlap it. It looks like maybe all texts are slightly shifted up, or it's ignoring the fact that some headers are on 2 lines.
Page count is still the same, which makes me think that "damage" is limited to this.

I have no clue if rendering now is accurate or if it was previous rendering that was accurate .
It would be easier for me to simply get my past rendering rather than to start tweaking this document (I mean this document is important but I don't use LaTeX on regular basis past this project.)

I still have all of the files/backups of previous system installation and project files.
So is there a way that I could simply replicate the rendering I was getting before system reinstallation?

---

*Still doing some tests and possibly preparing a working sample document, but can't share any of the actual document documents, will take a bit.*

Answer (score 1):

I found some solution. I think it's very ugly but it works for this issue.

Reinstalled Miktex 2.9.7342 (I am still not sure if I was actually using version 2.9.694 but installation process for 2.9.694 with the files that I have is very confusing so I installed 2.9.7342 )
Texmaker 5.0.4

Delete all files in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\  (target MiKTeX installation folder)

Copied all files from [old_drive]\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9* to C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9*

Comment: Among the possibilities (low likelihood, but possible) is that one or more of your fonts has been modified. Font designers sometimes release a font, then make a subtle change (such as kerning tables) later. Than can affect linebreaks, etc.